# Laravel run time interface binding depending on authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, containers

I have 2 classes that implement an interface, something like this:

```
interface SomeInterface
{
    public function init();
}

class ServiceOne implements SomeInterface
{
    public function init() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

class ServiceTwo implements SomeInterface
{
    public function init() {
        // ...
    }


    // ...
}
```

I can bind one or the other to the interface in Laravel using a service provider like this:

```
$this->app->bind('<NAMESPACE>\SomeInterface', '<NAMESPACE>\ServiceOne');
```

or:

```
$this->app->bind('<NAMESPACE>\SomeInterface', '<NAMESPACE>\ServiceTwo');
```

But I want to do it at run time based on a value set in the DB linked to the authenticated user so I need to get hold of the user and determine which to use.

I have tried getting the user in the boot method of a service provider and then binding the interface but I can't get a handle on the user there. Always returns null.

I have also tried using before middleware and trying to get the user directly from the request but that also returns null.

How would this kind of thing be done as I thought it would be a pretty standard thing to need to do?

Comment: I believe middleware is the appropriate place to handle this.  What's strange though is not being able to grab the user at that point.  That's exactly how the auth middleware works so you should have the logged in user available at that point.

Comment: I tried using before and after middleware and attempting to grab the user from the request always returns null. I've had to pass 2 services into a controller and then decided which one to actually use and then call an init method on that which would have done most of what the constructor did. I'm sure there mist be a better way of doing this in Laravel.